# Using HTML form action with a php script being in another directory (relative paths)

Tags: php, html, apache

Here's what my diretory tree looks like

```
/application
    /lib
    /util
        /login
    /views
        /base_view
```

My login page is

```
localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/views/base_view/index.php
```

And I want the action of my form to be this

```
localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/util/login/main.php
```

Here's my form declaration

```
<form class="form_login" action="./util/login/main.php" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

But when I click the submit button, it takes me to

```
localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/views/base_view/util/login/main.php
```

Which is the wrong path and generates a Error 404.

So what's wrong with the way I'm using relative paths in my form declaration and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your relative path `./util/login/main.php`, you're using `./` which refers to the current folder, so it assumes that the folder structure `/util/login` is inside `/base_view`. You should try using `../` which refers to the parent folder:

```
<form class="form_login" action="../../util/login/main.php" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: is there any reason why I should use the `../` twice? Or maybe a situation where I could use just one `../` ?

Comment: @Flayshon actually Yes there is a difference, basically in your case,  you start in `localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/views/base_view/`, if you use `../` once you'll end up in `localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/views/` and using it twice will get you to `localhost:737/astuto-lena/branches/application/` which is also the folder that contains `/util/login/`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the action to a better relative path or use an absolute path. Examples:

```
../../util/login/main.php
```

or

```
/astuto-lena/branches/application/util/login/main.php
```

`./` simply means `this directory` (aka `current working directory`)

Answer (score 1):

You must use .. / to go to parent directory

```
<form class="form_login" action="../../util/login/main.php" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the a similar problem and the error I got was object not found
`/application
    /includes
        connect.php
        insert.php
     index.php`

```
<form action="/includes/insert.php" method="post">
    //code
</form>
```

the above code didn't work and showed the error 404, Object Not Found. But,

```
<form action="./includes/insert.php" method="post">
    //code
</form>
```

The only difference is adding `.` in the action path.
The strange things is `/include/filename` works fine for `require` or `include` but you will need to add `.` for form action attribute