# Using HTML form action with a php script being in another directory

Tags: php, html

here is my path

```
main:
    Members/name.html
    search.php
```

Members is a folder

my html code:
 in name.html

```
    <form action="../search.php" method="get">
                            <div>
                                <br/>
                                <input type="text" name="input"  value="Search the
 site&hellip;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Search the site&hellip;')? 
'' : this.value ;" />
                                <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="GO" />
                            </div>
```

but when i ran this and put something in the search bar it didn't work.
i read this 
[Using HTML form action with a php script being in another directory (relative paths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967526/using-html-form-action-with-a-php-script-being-in-another-directory-relative-pa)
but it still doesn't work
when i put the html file in the same directory as the `search.php` it's working great (i'm changing the path to `./search.php`  when it's in the same directory)
but when i'm putting it back to the another directory it's not working again.

Comment: I'm assuming `main` is your root? If so, `/search.php` should work

Comment: Seems fine to me. Your HTML semantics are horrible but otherwise it should work. Any errors?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other error? I copy-pasted your code and worked fine. Maybe you should post your code in search.php

Comment: i have in my root index.html and there it work great with search.php
i don't get any errors only this in the browser bar
"...emtemplate.html?input=apple&go=GO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to the problem:

```
<form action=".././search.php" method="get">
```

i use `../` to go back in folders like "martijn" said
and `./` for the php use

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways. Let's assume you are at domein.ext **/dir1/dir2/**

If you want to post to the exact current url (if you have nice urls, this occurs):

```
<form> <!-- No target, only in HTML5 -->
```

If you have `page.php` in the same dir:

```
<form action="page.php">
```

If you are in dir2, and want a file from dir1 (so up 1 dir):

```
<form action="../page.php"> <!-- ../ means 'up one dir' -->
```

If you are in dir1, and need something in dir2:

```
<form action="./dir2/page.php"> <!-- ./ means 'current dir' -->
```

If you want the location to the resource to be checked from the domain, you start with slash:

```
<form action="/whole/different/dirs/page.php"> <!-- / means 'document root' -->
```

---

Handy to know, `./` and `../` are very common, they work in php includes, resources in webpages, commandline, etc etc.
Please note, the `/` in php doesnt mean 'document root', in php it will link to `/home` (on a LINUX server). Thats why you have `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`